# Draw one row of content for a carousel

Tags: javascript, css, inline

With the tagline JavaScript being the precluded implementing tool, I need a container that has the ability to slide sideways, without drawing down in rows. I have done multiple searches for key terms, like single row, inline, flexbox, and grid. But nothing has come up with a pure answer. So I need some help here, guys, and gals.

This is what I have on it right now. It draws very discrete lines of information, each one row. I might be answering my own question here, but should I put the `#carousel-window` a `parentNode` higher?

```
#carousel-window {
    display: inline-table;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.carousel-grid-box
{
    width:150px;
}
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<table style="width:100%;height:150;background-color:silver;color:black;" id="carousel-table" ajax="">
<tbody><tr><td>
    <img style="height:100%;width:100;position:relative;z-index:2" src="' + leftScrollButtonImg + '" onclick="carouselScrollLeft(this)"></td>
<td><section id="carousel-window" style="width:100%;vertical-align:super;" ajax=""></section></td>
<td><img style="height:100%;width:100;position:relative;z-index:2" src="' + rightScrollButtonImg + '" onclick="carouselScrollRight(this)">
</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// #carousel is the furthest point of the nest, the root node
// the table is any way you want to work it out.
#carousel, table {

    border-radius: 30px;
    width:900px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    overflow: clip;
    overflow-x: clip;
}
// I used this as the (of most importance) display:table
#carousel-house
{
    border-radius: 30px;
    overflow: clip;
    overflow-x: clip;
    width:400px;
    display:table;
    z-index:5;
}
// These buttons don't work out right
#carousel-button-left {
    z-index: 4;
    display:none;
    position: fixed;
    left:10px;
    top:45px;
}
#carousel-button-right {
    z-index: 4;
    display:none;
    position: fixed;
    left:770px;
    top:45px;
}
// This is the Child Node of the #carousel house (table:table-row)
#carousel-window {
    overflow-wrap:break-word;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    display:table-row;
}
// here we remove any scroll bars
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;  /* Remove scrollbar space */
    background: transparent;  /* Optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}
// Finally, and I did this within a Fetch
// I set the class to .carousel-cell and 
.carousel-cell {
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden hidden;
    text-align:justify;
    height:50px;
    width:150px;
    z-index:3;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

If you would like to see it working, you can try it out at [wise-penny/Adoms](https://www.github.com/wise-penny/Adoms) on github.com